# How to invert colors of an image using the Windows Imaging Component?

Tags: c++, wic

How can I invert the colors in an image using the Windows Imaging Component? I want to make white pixels black and black pixels white using the WIC. I tried using `IWICBitmapDecoder::CopyPalette` and `IWICPalette::GetColors` to retrieve the colors and invert them. But I couldn't do it successfully.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and with what image (code, image file, ...)?

Comment: [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) has lots of example source of using WIC to manipulate images.